# Big O: Prove that for all $x \leqslant y$, $n^x \in \mathcal O(n^y)$

Tags: asymptotics

For all real numbers, if  $x \leqslant y, n^x  \in \mathcal O(n^y)$.

This is a homework question, so I'm just looking for a little guidance with this question, and not the answer. I understand how to prove Big O questions using actual functions, but this is something new so I'm unsure. I know that I have to find a c and b that make this true, but I can't figure out how to do the algebra to arrive at that conclusion. Any hints with this?

So far, I've only got the first step:

$n^x \le c*(n^y)$

Where can I go from here?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the limit test helpful here. Let $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$. $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ if $L < \infty$. If $0 < L < \infty$, then $f(n) \in \Theta(g(n))$, which implies $f(n) \in O(g(n))$. Otherwise, if $L = 0$, then $f(n) \in o(g(n))$, which implies that $f(n) \in O(g(n))$.

Comment: How can I calculate the limit with f(n) = n^x and g(n) = n^y? Just choose any arbitrary values that satisfy x<=y?

Comment: It is not true that $f \in O(g)$ if and only if $L < \infty$; the limit may not exist.  If you had defined $L = \limsup_{n \to \infty} |f(n)/g(n)|$ then it would be true.

Comment: User134796- Think about applying L'Hosptial's rule. Note that since $x \leq y$, the limit will be at most $1$. If $x < y$, the limit will be $0$.

Antonio Vargas- Thanks for the catch. I've edited out the biconditional.